# Time evolution operator for photons passing through three polarizers in Dirac three polarizers experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, polarization

I am unable to find a representation online about the Dirac three polarizers experiment with a time development operator and Griffith's Consistent Histories treatment of the set up.  Would anyone like to present it here?